# How to convert individual list values inside a pandas DataFrame into string/float?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have fetched stock data from a website and made a pandas dataframe but there are some error like this photo below...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PP8l.jpg)

How can I solve this problem?...so that individual cell work like a float/ string instead of list?

Comment: Instead of trying to retrospectively change your data structure, you should post the code that imported the data and get advice on how to avoid ending up with lists as entries.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your dataframe is called `df`. You can simply run:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: getting this error ......TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem stems from the way you convert the incoming data to a dataframe. You can still write a filter function like the following code and apply it to your columns.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1': ['[0]', '[1]', '[2]']})

>>> get_digits = lambda x:int("".join(filter(str.isdigit, x)))

>>> df['column_1'].apply(func)

0    0
1    1
2    2
Name: column_1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: for response in responses:
            results.append(await response.json())                 
            df=pd.DataFrame(results)..........this is my code ...how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If your data are strings, use a regex to remove brackets:

```
df = df.replace(r'[\[\]]', '', regex=True)
```